# How do I remove the default transparent header in NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I navigate to another view that contains a scrollview via a NavigationLink I get some behaviour I want to remove.

When you scroll, the top of the view becomes filled with a different colour and blurs whatever is behind it.

How do I remove this effect? Here is the code and some photos showing the effect:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to detail view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Click for image]

I was expecting to be able to remove this with some modifiers but cannot seem to find the correct one if this is in fact the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 16, you can hide the navigation bar with this modifier on the `Destination`:

```
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```

[image: Hidden]

and make it have a custom color like:

```
.toolbarBackground(.red, for: .navigationBar)
```

[image: Colored]

Here is the full code:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView().toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)) {
                    Text("Go to detail view (hidden navigation)")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView().toolbarBackground(.orange, for: .navigationBar)) {
                    Text("Go to detail view (orange navigation)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                Circle().fill(.red)
                Circle().fill(.blue)
                Circle().fill(.yellow)
                Circle().fill(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That first example you provided is exactly what I am looking for however I can't seem to replicate it, I am on iOS 17. Is this code correct? NavigationLink(destination:  DetailView().toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)) {
                Text("Go to detail view")
            }

Comment: I have added a complete code. Tested on iOS 17 preview inside Xcode 15

Comment: Also, make sure you are not using other work arounds for changing the navigation bar color.

Comment: That's great thanks! I marked as correct, can't upvote due to low reputation score

Answer (score 0):

Modify `DetailView` with [`.toolbarBackground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbarbackground(_:for:)-5ybst), and set the navigation bar's background to an opaque color (e.g. `.white`).

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink {
        DetailView().toolbarBackground(.white, for: .navigationBar)
    } label: {
        Text("Go to detail view")
    }
}
```